# Method Chaining Call to a member function on a non-object

Tags: php

I'm working on a program that gets a user input, then returns the plural/singular form of the typed in word. I have acquired a library/class for this which contains a `singularize()` and `pluralize()` method. Code Below.

```
$pluralString = new Inflector();
print_r($pluralString->pluralize($queryString)->singularize($queryString));
```

The code above returns: Fatal error:  Call to a member function singularize() on a non-object.

Comment: Whatever `$pluralString->pluralize($queryString)` returns is not an object you are looking for. It most likely will be null or a string.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/). See ["Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts)". BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Wendell Inflector is one of many utility classes that ship with Lithium out of the box. But the singularize and pluralize are the static functions, try to look to the code here : https://github.com/UnionOfRAD/lithium/blob/master/util/Inflector.php and for the tutorials look here: http://nitschinger.at/Understanding-the-Inflector

So, as they are static functions, try to use like this:

```php
Inflector::pluralize($queryString);
Inflector::singularize($queryString);
```

Also, if you want to add your own rules for the singular and plural

```php
Inflector::rules('singular', array('/rata/' => '\1ratus'));
```

But remeber it is also static function.

Hope this helps